# Retrieve value from an php array

Tags: php, arrays

Im new to php and developing. please find below the code i used.

```
$data['ques']=$this->questions_model->displayquestionbyid($questionid);
var_dump($data);
```

The out put prints as

```
array(1) { ["ques"]=> array(1) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#19 (6) { ["questionid"]=> string(1) "1" ["votecount"]=> string(1) "0" ["username"]=> string(3) "hip" ["catogoryid"]=> string(1) "2" ["questionTitle"]=> string(4) "e2e2" ["description"]=> string(6) " deded" } } }
```

How do i take value of `username` and save it under php variable.Thank you

Comment: In which framework you are use.

Comment: try echo $data['ques'][0]->username;

Comment: Above comment should solve your issue, but just to make your output more readable you can use `echo "<pre>"; print_r($data); echo "</pre>";` instead of `var_dump($data);` for debugging.

Comment: Read a php book this is basic stuff!

Comment: @ Rakesh Sharma your correct dude it works

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell from the output format you gave, but you probably want to do:

```
$data = $this->questions_model->displayquestionbyid($questionid);

$username = $data[0]->username;
```

Comment: A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Trying to get property of non-object
Filename: controllers/homepage.php
Line Number: 120

Comment: $data[0]->username; ?

Comment: That's probably right, based on his output.  Try that, @user3423301

Answer (score 0):

```
$data = $this->questions_model->displayquestionbyid($questionid);

$username = $data['ques'][0]->username;
```

check if this works and please debug using print_r() instead.